# is there a decent IDE that supports C intellisense but not C++?

Tags: c, ide, intellisense

I use visual studio but I find that since the compiler is a c++ compiler I keep getting annoyed by all the c++ intelligence. id like to code in something that keeps me in c. 
Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm curious: Can you provide examples of what C++ intellisense bothers you while writing a strict C project ?...

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [clang auto-completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) has great support for C.

You can quickly switch between C and C++ using `c-mode` and `c++-mode`, even when using a C++ compiler (by default Emacs doesn't look at the compiler, but at the source file extension).

---

Xcode 3 will also stop suggesting C++ code when writing C and vice-versa. Xcode 4 will do this too, but you asked for a *decent* IDE.